# Initialize a Behavioursubject with a function call

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have an angular service that is supposed to send data to 2 components that display it simultaneously and both can change that data which changes the display of it on both components. I have chosen to use a BehaviourSubject in the service to store and emit that shared data between the components.
I get the data that is to be displayed from a http.get
The problem is that I have to have a value from the start in the behavioursubject and I don't want to hardcode it but want to call the function.

I wanted to do something like this:

```
private selectedPersonSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Person>(this.getPerson(1));
getPerson(id: number):Observable<Person>{ 
    return this.http.get(baseUrl + id).pipe(map(data => data as Person));
  }
```

then i get the following error
Argument of type 'Observable' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Person'.
I know that I could subscribe to getPerson in the constructor and get a Person Object but that doesnt solve the problem of the initialization and the required starting value for the behavioursubject.
Any Ideas?

I also tried to initialize the Behavioursubject with null which of course doesnt work and hardcoding it but that isn't really what I'm trying to accomplish

EDIT: I solved the issue

```
  public selectedPersonSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
```

It seems i overcomplicated it. I think it could maybe be cleaner but for now this is ok

Answer (score 2):

I'm not allowed to write comments yet, therefore, I'm gonna write down my thoughts here:

Have you already had a look to https://angular.io/api/router/ResolveFn?
Using the ResolveFn, you can wait for some data to be resolved before the component is loaded.
I could imagine that your ResolveFn calls an initPerson-method in your service, which does the api-call and initalizes the BehaviourSubject. The BehaviourSubject will then be ready when the component is loading. Of course, the initPerson method would only need to do the api-call the first time it is called.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is one of possible solutions:

```
private selectedPersonSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<Person>(null);

getPerson(id: number):Observable<Person>{ 
  this.http.get(baseUrl + id).pipe(map(data => data as Person))
  .subscribe(data => this.selectedPersonSubject$.next(data));
}
```

Don't forget to 'kill' all the subscriptions (inside ngOnDestroy(), as variant).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `any`, and losing the type information for your `BehaviorSubject` object, you can define its type to also accept null like below

```
private selectedPersonSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Person | null>(null);
```